# Ajax request to php failing?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to do an ajax request to my php, but for some unknown reason it seems to fail as i don't get to the success part where I have a `console.log`

Can anyone please give me some hint what might be wron with this, I am stuck for too long now??

Here is how my jQuery looks :

```
getPending();
function getPending(){
var usernameLS = localStorage.getItem('userNameLS');
var userTypeLS = localStorage.getItem('isAdminLS');

    if (userTypeLS!=1) {
        console.log("inside");//i am getting here
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'get-pending.php',
            data: {
                data: usernameLS //this is a string, "user2" for instance
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("Thanks!!!",data);//i never got here

            },
            failure: function() {
                console.log("Error!");
                alert(' Fail');
            }
        });
       }
```

And here is my php :

```
<?php
$string = file_get_contents("appointments.json");
$usernameAjax = $_POST['data'];
var_dump($usernameAjax);
$json_a = json_decode($string, true);
$isPending;
foreach ($json_a as &$json_r) {
    if ($usernameAjax==$json_r['userName'] && $json_r['status'] = "Pending") {

        $isPending = 1;
      }
      else{
        $isPending = 0;
      }
}
var_dump($isPending);
echo $isPending; //i tried with a hardcodede 1 or 0 zero. Didn't work.
?>
```

Comment: Add to the failure function(error) and log the error.message.

Comment: Put at very top of your PHP file `error_reporting(E_ALL);` statement

Comment: It doesn't log an error.

Comment: You are requestiing json but not returning json

Comment: Remove the `var_dump();` statements, they will mess with the returned result - they will make it non-valid JSON

Comment: Also there is no `failure` property of `$.ajax. See docs for various error handlers and use their arguments properly to help troubleshoot

Comment: If you want to debug PHP side, you can still use `var_dump` or `print_r`, but you will have to open the developper tool (F12 in most browser), and then switch to `Network` tab. When you execute your Ajax call, a new line will appear. Click on it and look at the `Response` tab. It will show you everything printed on the PHP script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your output is not correct JSON format, so client-side cant understand what was recieved.

First - remove **var_dump**, it breaks json format anyway;

Second - jou just output **1** or **0** - that is not correct json too; use **json_encode** to format reply properly;

Third - php files often contains trailing symbols after **?>**, that are appends to output too and could break output format. Dont close php with **?>** at all; additionally you could use **die($output)** instead of **echo($output)** to avoid any output after your data was written